# How to use plurals correctly when using the sizeof function in php?

Tags: php

When the page display results, I want it to say say *"We found X products"* or *"We found 1 Product"* rather than *"we found 1 products"*.

The relevant part of my current code is this:

```
<?php echo sizeof($ids); ?> Products</strong>
```

How could I extend it to behave more natural?

Comment: You can use count($ids) to see if there is more than one and use this to conditionally output the 's'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If count is more than one echo "s".

```
<?php echo sizeof($ids); ?> Product <?php If(count($ids)>1) echo "s"; ?></strong>
```

Or you make it easier to read like this:.

```
If(count($ids)>1) {
    Echo sizeof($ids) . " Products.</strong>";
}Else{
    Echo sizeof($ids) . " Product.</strong>";
}
```

Comment: Odd to use `sizeof` AND `count` especially on the same line.

Comment: @abra true.. I just copy paste and added "my" way of writing. It's easier to copy paste as much as possible when you type on the phone